# sql grouping into one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, sql-server-2008

I wrote following sql query for a report.

```
Select AT.OTHER_GL_CODE As ACC,
       GL.GL_ID,
       GL.GL_NAME,
       (Case When (
                      AT.OTHER_TRN_DEC = 'Cash'
                      And AT.OTHER_CR_DR = 'CR'
                  ) Then AT.OTHER_AMOUNT
             Else '0'
        End
       ) As 'CASHCR',
       (Case When (
                      AT.OTHER_TRN_DEC = 'Cash'
                      And AT.OTHER_CR_DR = 'DR'
                  ) Then AT.OTHER_AMOUNT
             Else '0'
        End
       ) As 'CASHDR',
       (Case When (
                      AT.OTHER_TRN_DEC <> 'Cash'
                      And AT.OTHER_CR_DR = 'CR'
                  ) Then AT.OTHER_AMOUNT
             Else '0'
        End
       ) As 'OTHERCR',
       (Case When (
                      AT.OTHER_TRN_DEC <> 'Cash'
                      And AT.OTHER_CR_DR = 'DR'
                  ) Then AT.OTHER_AMOUNT
             Else '0'
        End
       ) As 'OTHERDR',
       AT.OTHER_BRN_CODE BRNCODE,
       (
           Select Sum(   Case When TR.CR_DR = 'DR'
                                   And TR.BRANCH_CODE = 1000
                                   And TR.TRAN_DATE < '2017-07-01' Then TR.GL_TRN_AMT
                              Else 0
                         End
                     )
           From   COREBANKER1.dbo.GL_DAILY_TRN As TR
           Where  TR.GL_CODE = AT.OTHER_GL_CODE
       ) As DRBRFORE,
       (
           Select Sum(   Case When TR.CR_DR = 'CR'
                                   And TR.BRANCH_CODE = 1000
                                   And TR.TRAN_DATE < '2017-07-01' Then TR.GL_TRN_AMT
                              Else 0
                         End
                     )
           From   COREBANKER1.dbo.GL_DAILY_TRN As TR
           Where  TR.GL_CODE = AT.OTHER_GL_CODE
       ) As CRBRFORE
From   COREBANKER1.dbo.MAIN_OTHER_TRN As AT,
       COREBANKER1.dbo.GL_MAIN As GL
Where  AT.OTHER_BRN_CODE = 1000
       And GL.GL_ID = AT.OTHER_GL_CODE
       And AT.OTHER_BANK_DATE
       Between '2017-07-01' And '2017-07-30';
```

this is the output

[image]

but  my desired output is here

[image]

So how I change my query for desired result(grouping to ACC and GL_ID)?

Comment: The first thing you should do is start using ANSI-92 style joins, they have been around for more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins Then for people to be able to provide an answer you need to provide some details. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: It looks like you just need to add a `GROUP BY` and `SUM()` aggregates...

Comment: wrap each of those case statements with sum() and group by the first three columns as @Siyual stated

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty approach is to wrap the entire query and group by, this would prevent duplicate values in your 3,4,5, 6th columns.

The cleaner approach would be to take those 4 columns and wrap each one in a `Select SUM(...)` as you did for the later columns.

In short, no `GROUP BY` will leave you with duplicates - I took the liberty of giving you the syntax for the quick and dirty approach, see below.

```
SELECT
    ACC
    ,GL_ID
    ,GL_NAME
    ,SUM(CASHCR) AS CASHCR
    ,SUM(CASHDR) AS CASHDR
    ,SUM(OTHERCR) AS OTHERCR
    ,SUM(OTHERDR) AS OTHERDR
    ,BRNCODE
    ,DRBRFORE
    ,CRBRFORE
FROM (
    Select AT.OTHER_GL_CODE As ACC,
           GL.GL_ID,
           GL.GL_NAME,
           (Case When (
                          AT.OTHER_TRN_DEC = 'Cash'
                          And AT.OTHER_CR_DR = 'CR'
                      ) Then AT.OTHER_AMOUNT
                 Else '0'
            End
           ) As 'CASHCR',
           (Case When (
                          AT.OTHER_TRN_DEC = 'Cash'
                          And AT.OTHER_CR_DR = 'DR'
                      ) Then AT.OTHER_AMOUNT
                 Else '0'
            End
           ) As 'CASHDR',
           (Case When (
                          AT.OTHER_TRN_DEC <> 'Cash'
                          And AT.OTHER_CR_DR = 'CR'
                      ) Then AT.OTHER_AMOUNT
                 Else '0'
            End
           ) As 'OTHERCR',
           (Case When (
                          AT.OTHER_TRN_DEC <> 'Cash'
                          And AT.OTHER_CR_DR = 'DR'
                      ) Then AT.OTHER_AMOUNT
                 Else '0'
            End
           ) As 'OTHERDR',
           AT.OTHER_BRN_CODE BRNCODE,
           (
               Select Sum(   Case When TR.CR_DR = 'DR'
                                       And TR.BRANCH_CODE = 1000
                                       And TR.TRAN_DATE < '2017-07-01' Then TR.GL_TRN_AMT
                                  Else 0
                             End
                         )
               From   COREBANKER1.dbo.GL_DAILY_TRN As TR
               Where  TR.GL_CODE = AT.OTHER_GL_CODE
           ) As DRBRFORE,
           (
               Select Sum(   Case When TR.CR_DR = 'CR'
                                       And TR.BRANCH_CODE = 1000
                                       And TR.TRAN_DATE < '2017-07-01' Then TR.GL_TRN_AMT
                                  Else 0
                             End
                         )
               From   COREBANKER1.dbo.GL_DAILY_TRN As TR
               Where  TR.GL_CODE = AT.OTHER_GL_CODE
           ) As CRBRFORE
    From   COREBANKER1.dbo.MAIN_OTHER_TRN As AT,
           COREBANKER1.dbo.GL_MAIN As GL
    Where  AT.OTHER_BRN_CODE = 1000
           And GL.GL_ID = AT.OTHER_GL_CODE
           And AT.OTHER_BANK_DATE
           Between '2017-07-01' And '2017-07-30'
)A
GROUP BY 
    ACC
    ,GL_ID
    ,GL_NAME
    ,CASHCR
    ,CASHDR
    ,OTHERCR
    ,OTHERDR
    ,BRNCODE
    ,DRBRFORE
    ,CRBRFORE   
           ;
```

Comment: Try posting some sample data on one of the sharing sites and sharing a link here. Examples are: http://sqlfiddle.com/ and https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could surround your query with a CTE then aggregate the fields you require.

```
WITH this as 
(
Select AT.OTHER_GL_CODE As ACC,
   GL.GL_ID,
   GL.GL_NAME,
   (Case When (
                  AT.OTHER_TRN_DEC = 'Cash'
                  And AT.OTHER_CR_DR = 'CR'
              ) Then AT.OTHER_AMOUNT
         Else '0'
    End
   ) As 'CASHCR',
   (Case When (
                  AT.OTHER_TRN_DEC = 'Cash'
                  And AT.OTHER_CR_DR = 'DR'
              ) Then AT.OTHER_AMOUNT
         Else '0'
    End
   ) As 'CASHDR',
   (Case When (
                  AT.OTHER_TRN_DEC <> 'Cash'
                  And AT.OTHER_CR_DR = 'CR'
              ) Then AT.OTHER_AMOUNT
         Else '0'
    End
   ) As 'OTHERCR',
   (Case When (
                  AT.OTHER_TRN_DEC <> 'Cash'
                  And AT.OTHER_CR_DR = 'DR'
              ) Then AT.OTHER_AMOUNT
         Else '0'
    End
   ) As 'OTHERDR',
   AT.OTHER_BRN_CODE BRNCODE,
   (
       Select Sum(   Case When TR.CR_DR = 'DR'
                               And TR.BRANCH_CODE = 1000
                               And TR.TRAN_DATE < '2017-07-01' Then TR.GL_TRN_AMT
                          Else 0
                     End
                 )
       From   COREBANKER1.dbo.GL_DAILY_TRN As TR
       Where  TR.GL_CODE = AT.OTHER_GL_CODE
   ) As DRBRFORE,
   (
       Select Sum(   Case When TR.CR_DR = 'CR'
                               And TR.BRANCH_CODE = 1000
                               And TR.TRAN_DATE < '2017-07-01' Then TR.GL_TRN_AMT
                          Else 0
                     End
                 )
       From   COREBANKER1.dbo.GL_DAILY_TRN As TR
       Where  TR.GL_CODE = AT.OTHER_GL_CODE
   ) As CRBRFORE
From   COREBANKER1.dbo.MAIN_OTHER_TRN As AT,
   COREBANKER1.dbo.GL_MAIN As GL
Where  AT.OTHER_BRN_CODE = 1000
   And GL.GL_ID = AT.OTHER_GL_CODE
   And AT.OTHER_BANK_DATE
   Between '2017-07-01' And '2017-07-30';
)
)
SELECT ACC ,GL_ID ,GL_NAME, SUM(CASHCR) AS CASHCR ,SUM(CASHDR) AS CASHDR ,SUM(OTHERCR) AS OTHERCR ,SUM(OTHERDR) AS OTHERDR, BRNCODE, DRBRFORE, CRBRFORE
FROM this
GROUP BY ACC ,GL_ID ,GL_NAME /*,CASHCR ,CASHDR ,OTHERCR ,OTHERDR */,BRNCODE 
,DRBRFORE ,CRBRFORE
```

Comment: this query result was same.I need to group into one row CASHCR,CASHDR,OTHERCR,OTHERDR for same account

Comment: @SandeepKumar , I have updated it, I hadn't taken into consideration that I didn't need to group by the aggregates, as that would keep the figures separate.